Persistence on Hadoop-Spark using Docker container
no way how create containers with hadoop and spark with persistence of data. Everytime shutdown containers (docker-compose "down") I lose al data inside of the hdfs file system.
I tried several things like create a volume linked to the "ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name" defined on docker-compose.yml but there are a permission error. To avoid the permission erros i tried to create the container using the parameter "user: root" on docker-compose.yml but nothing change.
I tried to change that directory to another one like "/data/" and create a volume linked to this folder and also in the config file changing the value of :
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.datanode.data.dir=/data.
I know I am close of the solution but I need your help guys.
I´ve attach the docker-compose.yml and config file:
docker-compose.yml
version: "2"
services:
   namenode:
       image: apache/hadoop:3
       hostname: namenode
       command: ["hdfs", "namenode"]
       ports:
           - 9870:9870
       volumes:
           - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
       env_file:
           - ./config
       environment:
           #ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
           ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/data"
   datanode:
       image: apache/hadoop:3
       user: root
       command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
       env_file:
           - ./config
       volumes:
       #    - ./data:/data
           - datanode-volume:/data
           - config-datanodo-volume:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
       #    - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
   resourcemanager:
       image: apache/hadoop:3
       hostname: resourcemanager
       command: ["yarn", "resourcemanager"]
       ports:
           - 8088:8088
       env_file:
           - ./config
       volumes:
           - ./test.sh:/opt/test.sh
   nodemanager:
       image: apache/hadoop:3
       command: ["yarn", "nodemanager"]
       env_file:
           - ./config
   pyspark:
       image: jupyter/all-spark-notebook
       volumes:
           - ./pyspark:/home/jovyan
           - pyspark-volume:/home/jovyan/work
       ports:
           - 8888:8888
volumes:
   datanode-volume:
   pyspark-volume:
   config-datanodo-volume:
   hadoop_namenode:
   #hadoop_datanode:


config
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.default.name=hdfs://namenode
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.namenode.rpc-address=namenode:8020
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.replication=1
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.datanode.data.dir=/data
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
MAPRED-SITE.XML_yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.map.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=resourcemanager
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec=600
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=default
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state=RUNNING
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings=
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable=false

